# Pinescript in Verion5 for example ema

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I found this code for ema. It doesn't work in v5 anymore. I know that ema is in the pinescript library. It is only an example for calculating over an interval.

I tried this code:

```
*calcEma(oVector, period) =>
    var float volatility = 0.0

    var float sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to period - 1
        sum += oVector[i] / period
    sum
*
```

I expecting the ema, but only get an constant value.

Must I write out the outer loop. If yes, how must I code it?

Answer (score 0):

The var keyword must be deleted in the definition of sum. It also must be tied to float. Variant definition also doesn't work.

Comment: Mistake: float can optionally be removed. <0.0> ties it to float

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).